# Augumented matrix in reduced row echelon form - find number of solutions

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am asked to determine if the following system has no solution, a unique solution, or infinitely many solutions.

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}

My attempted to transform it into reduced row echelon form:

Switch rows 1 and 3

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

Row 1 = (Row 2 * (-1)) + Row 1 
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

Row 2 = (Row 3 * (-1)) + Row 2 
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

The solution in the textbook says it has a unique solution. I don't understand this because there appears to be a free variable in the 4th column, which should make it an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: Your RREF is correct. Isn't your matrix $Ax = b$? In this case, you found $z=0, y = 1, x = 0$, a unique solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have another question - if the last row of this matrix is all 0s, does that mean it has an infinite number of solutions? Because for another example, my RREF had a 3rd row full of 0s, but it states it has a unique solution like this one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825515/how-does-a-row-of-zeros-make-a-free-variable-in-linear-systems-of-equations